# Selecting a data frame from a list of data frames as an argument in a function in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, arguments

Hey I'd like to use a `data.frame` from a large `list` as an argument in a function. My data has a list of NBA team data where each team is a `data.frame` in the `list`; for the function I made to be most effective, I would need to use the team as an argument. Here is some test data:

```
a<- data.frame(1,1:10)
b<- data.frame("a",4,"d", 20:25)

c<- list(a,b)
names(c)<- c("a","b")

test<- function(df){
  poop<- subset(c$df, c$df$X1.10==1)
  return(poop)
}
```

In this example I would want to run something like

```
test("a")
```

but I'm struggling to get it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: Do `test(c[[1]])`. c[[1]] is the first data frame of the list. And you should rewrite your function to work with a local data frame (not the list c)

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you wanted. I did some rewriting. First, for the function to return a data frame in the global environment, you should use "<<". If not, you can keep "<-". But remember that as a local variable, the data frame will exist only when the function is running.This is similar to the global assignment of a variable in Python.
Second, there is a better way to subset the data frame as I show below:

```
a<- data.frame(1,1:10)
b<- data.frame("a",4,"d", 20:25)

c<- list(a,b)
names(c)<- c("a","b")

test<- function(df){
    poop<<- subset(df, df$X1.10==1)
    return(poop)
}

test(c[[1]])
```